# How do I set up a global method or Vue directive that can access the shared data in a Laravel Inertia app to help restrict features by permissions?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3, mixins, inertiajs

I'm creating an app using Laravel Inertia.

I'm using Spatie's Laravel Permission package to handle authorisation and I'm trying to find a way to have a global `can` method or `directive` so that I can show or hide elements in the UI based on a user's permissions.

I know that I can send through permissions from my controller or via the `HandleInertiaRequest` middleware and then check against these in a vue component like this.

```
<button v-if="$page.props.auth.user.can['view users']">View Users</button>
```

And this works pretty well. But it would be nice if I can make something that's available globally and a little easier to remember. For example.

```
<button v-if="can('view users')">View Users</button>
```

or

```
<button v-can="'view users'">View Users</button>
```

However, I'm struggling to figure out what the best practice would be to achieve this.

I've tried to add a method to the `globalProperties` property in the `setup()` like so...

```
myApp.config.globalProperties.can = (permission) => {
  return props.initialPage.props.admin.data.can[permission];
};
```

This half works but the problem with this is that I have to refresh the page whenever the permissions are updated, despite me passing the allowed permissions through via the Inertia middleware.

I've also considered creating a Mixin but I believe this isn't the recommend approach for Vue 3. This lead me to looking at the `provide()` and `inject()` features of vue 3 but I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree with those.

So I guess my question is how can I have a global method or vue directive that reads from shared data in a Laravel Inertia app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by implementing a module and import it globally. Something like this for instance should work for what you are trying to achieve.

```
export default class Auth {
constructor (params) {
    this.user = params.user
    this.role = params.role

}

/**
 * Determines what a user has permission to see.
 * 
 * @param {String} ability 
 * @returns Boolean
 */
can (ability) {

    if (this.store[ability]) {
        return this.store[ability]
    }

    const parts = ability.split(':')

    if (parts.length !== 3) {
        return false
    }

    const [ prefix, level, resource ] = parts

    if (['create', 'read', 'update', 'delete'].indexOf(level) === -1) {
        console.warn(`Incorrect permission method "${level}".`)
        return false
    }

}

hasRole (roles) {
    if (Array.isArray(roles)) {
        for(let i=0;i<roles.length;i++) {
            if (this.hasRole(roles[i])) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return this.role === roles
}
```

You can then import the module in your app.js like so;

```
import Auth from '@/Modules/Auth'
```

The use the method the way you wanted, although in this case, I am using `v-if`

```
<button v-if="auth.can('view users)">View Users</button>
```

Comment: Not sure how this would fit in with an inertia app, but I think it would still give me the same problem, where i'd have to refresh the page to get any updated permissions to work. Because I wouldn't have access to Inertia shared data in the can function. As far as I'm aware, inertia doesn't give me a "store" like you'd get in a normal Vue app.

Comment: This was used in an Inertia App and not a generic Vue app. Each request on page load will contain the specific permission that the user has passed on from Laravel into the props passed to Inertia frontend. In your AppServiceProvider, whatever you provide in `Inertia::share()` function gets passed to the frontend, in the case of the above, something like this;
Inertia::share([
            'auth' => function () {
                $user = Auth::user();  
                     return [

Comment: Ah ok my apologies! I'll look at this again then. Just a tad confused because you check `this.store[ability]`. Where does `this.store` come from? Is this where Inertia keeps it's shared data? Because i've been accessing it through `$page.props` so far.